Styling a <dl> with automatic <dt> width
In CSS, I'm trying to style a definition list in columns, much like a table, where the <dt> and <dd> are side by side. The width of the <dt> "column" dynamically takes up as much width as it needs without text wrapping, and the <dd> gives it the necessary room.
I've accomplished this using a display: grid; layout:
dl { display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr; grid-gap: 10px; }
dd { grid-column-start: 2; }

(No styling on the <dt> elements.)
This is working as I need it. Yay.

Problem is...there are a couple of monkey wrenches.

There are some definitions with an "invisible" <dt> ("invisible" as in the left margin is off the screen so that users can't see it but screen readers will still read it). The reason for this is this is a list of products where the product title is obvious to visual users because of sizing, but I'd still like screen readers to say "product title." Visual users will just see, for instance, "Flux capacitor," but screen readers will say "Product title: Flux capacitor." In cases like this, even though the <dt> is out of the way, the <dd> is still giving it the room it needs, leaving a gap on the left. The text "Product title" should align all the way to the left, no margin. I can set a negative margin-left to move it over, but with changing text and, therefore, changing <dt> spacing, the spacing might not always be the same.

What I've got:

What I want:


The product image, also contained in the <dl>, needs to appear on the right with text wrapping around it, like a corner image. This has an invisible <dt> as well. So the <dt> will be "Product image" and the <dd> will be an <img> element with the appropriate alt text. (Never mind that non-visual users won't care to hear "product image" for an element that doesn't matter to them. I'll figure something out for this later.) I can set my placement with position: absolute; and right: 0;, but then if any text extends far enough, it goes behind the image since position: absolute; removes the image from the visual flow.

What I've got using position: absolute; (with a picture of a cute puppy to brighten your day):

I can set the <dd> with text-align: right, but the <dt> still leaves a vertical gap, pushing all proceeded <dt> elements down.
What I've got using align-right:

What I want:

Can anyone help me with these two problems? Am I way off track using display: grid;? Any ideas are welcome!

For problem 1, style your title with grid column: 1 / span 2. For problem 2, you’ll need to style the image with float: right and then probably use clear: right on a subsequent element. If you edit your post to include a runnable stack snippet we can answer more precisely and even demonstrate a working solution.

Thanks so much, @BrettDonald! Problem 1 is completely solved, it seems. I'm still having issues with problem 2 and the clears, but I'm going to do some tinkering and, if that works, post what I've got here. If it doesn't, I'll look into doing a stack snippet to show what's happening.

Nope. Couldn't figure it out, even with various Google searches. :/ I've set up a Jfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/wrcu1p24/4/. Let me know if I need to add anything more to it. It's my first Jfiddle, so I'm not sure if it's complete.

Float will only work within an inline formatting context, in this case, within a single grid item. You can float an image within a grid item and any text also in that grid item will flow around the image. But you can't have a float which spans/affects multiple grid items. You'll need to adjust your design.

That's disappointing. :/ I've searched high and low on the Internet and can't come up with a solution that gives my dt/dd pairs an automatic width and still lets me keep the product images as inset on the top-right corner. display: grid doesn't work. display: table doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution?

Change your design. Put the image in column3, or put it above the grid.

Thanks, I already tried making a 3-column grid, but problem is I'm not sure of the image's height, so I don't know how many rows down it will extend. (So I don't know at which row I can start extending my content all the way to the right.)
I'll think of some other design ideas, and as a last resort, put it above the grid. If I need to, I'll come back. Thanks for the help on this so far!

You could use Javascript to make adjustments to your layout after the image has loaded and you know its dimensions. But how finicky do you want to get? Remember that people will use your site on a variety of screen sizes, more often than not using their phone. What does your mobile design look like? I generally find that if you design (or build) the mobile layout first, the desktop layout becomes a fairly simple rearrangement of that.
